# JavaScript: detect if argument is array instead of object (Node.JS)

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, node.js, typeof

How should I detect if the argument is an array because `typeof []` returns `'object'` and I want to distinguish between arrays and objects.

It is possible that object will look like `{"0":"string","1":"string","length":"2"}` but I don't want it to come out as an array if it is in fact an object looking like an array.

`JSON.parse` and `JSON.stringify` are able to make this distinction. How can I do it?

I am using Node.JS which is based on V8 the same as Chrome.

Answer (score 171, accepted):

- `Array.isArray`

native V8 function. It's fast, it's always correct. This is part of ES5.

- `arr instanceof Array`

Checks whether the object was made with the array constructor.

- [`_.isArray // underscore method.`](http://underscorejs.org/#isArray)

A method from underscore. Here is a snippet taken from the their source

```
var toString = Object.prototype.toString,
    nativeIsArray = Array.isArray;
_.isArray = nativeIsArray || function(obj) {
    return toString.call(obj) === '[object Array]';
};
```

This method takes an object and calls the `Object.prototype.toString` method on it. This will always return `[object Array]` for arrays.

In my personal experience I find asking the `toString` method is the most effective but it's not as short or readable as `instanceof Array` nor is it as fast as `Array.isArray` but that's ES5 code and I tend to avoid using it for portability.

I would personally recommend you try using [`underscore`](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/), which is a library with common utility methods in it. It has a lot of useful functions that DRY up your code.

Comment: Use node.js `util` library - `require('util').isArray(arr)` https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_isarray_object

Comment: gentle reminder, don't us require('util').isArray(arr) in node v4.00 and above. It's deprecated

Comment: Somehow, in Node 10.x it looks like `arr instanceof Array` fails. However the `Array.isArray()` works great.

Answer (score 76):

Try this code:

```
Array.isArray(argument)
```

Answer (score 8):

How about:

```
your_object instanceof Array
```

In V8 in Chrome I get

```
[] instanceof Array
> true
({}) instanceof Array
> false 
({"0":"string","1":"string","length":"2"}) instanceof Array
> false
```

Answer (score 7):

I looks like this question has several good answers, but for completeness I would add another option, which have not been suggested earlier.

In order to check if something is an array, you can use Node.js `util` native module and its `isArray()` function.

Example:

```
var util = require('util');

util.isArray([]);  // true
util.isArray(new Array); // true
util.isArray({"0":"string","1":"string","length":"2"}); // false
```

With that method you do not have to worry about JS standards implemented by V8 as it will always show the right answer.

Comment: FWIW, `util.isArray()` currently proxies to `Array.isArray()`:  https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/95dbb6bf647d90947c0c738533dadf391559be98/lib/util.js#L508

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:
console.log(Object.prototype.toString.call(arg).replace(/^[object (.+)]$/, '$1').toLowerCase())

Comment: It might work, but it is pretty unreadable and absolutely cryptic over what that piece of code is actually doing. I would suggest to stick to something more clear like `Array.isArray(variable)`, for the sanity of who will read the code in few years.